# jQuery error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery in my page that keeps giving the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

In this code.

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var t1 = $("#main-page").offset().top;
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= t1) {   
        $('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color: #fff"});
        }
    });
```

Firebug says it is on this line: `$('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color: #fff"});`

I can't seem to find why it is giving this error.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color: #fff"});
```

To:

```
$('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color": "#fff"});
```

Also note that scroll event is fired many times, I'd suggest:

```
.white-bg { background-color: #fff }
```

```
var timeout = '',
    offset = $("#main-page").offset().top,
    $elem = $('#menu-item-70');

$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    timeout = setTimout(function(){
       $elem.toggleClass('white-bg', top >= offset);
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've done the CSS object incorrectly:

```
    $('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color": "#fff"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were using css() wrong.

Try changing:

```
$('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color: #fff"});
```

To:

```
$('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color": "#fff"});
```

So your full code looks like this:

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
     var t1 = $("#main-page").offset().top;
     if($(this).scrollTop() >= t1) {   
        $('#menu-item-70').css({"background-color": "#fff"});
     }
 });
```